# How to enumerate 1; 2.1; 2.2; 3?

Tags: numbering, enumerate

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Initials
\item Age
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Preliminary Condition
      \item Support
      \end{enumerate}
\item Imaging
\end{document}
```

Output

```
1
2
   a) 
   b)
3
```

Wanted output:

```
1
2
3.1 
3.2
4
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{1.8ex}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Initials
\item Age
          \stepcounter{enumi}
      \begin{enumerate}
      \item Preliminary Condition
      \item Support
      \end{enumerate}
\item Imaging
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it is possible. see edited answer.

Comment: Great idea in using `\theenumii`!

Comment: That's clever, @Zarko!  Do you really need the second line, though?

Comment: That is certainly possible, which does not mean that it is good style. You would (usually) not start a subsection 3.1 without starting section 3, either.

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to sacrifice automation entirely, then you could use custom labels throughout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [1] Initials
        \item [2] Age
        \item [3.1] Preliminary Condition
        \item [3.2] Support
        \item [4] Imaging
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you just use custom labels on the 3.1 and 3.2 parts, then the Imaging item gets numbered 3 instead of 4.  Hmm, how to do this can keep automation.  I will think further.

Comment: `\stepcounter{enumi}`, I think.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an automated version using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\setenumerate[1]{align=left,label=\arabic*}
\setenumerate[2]{before=\stepcounter{enumi},label*=.\arabic*,leftmargin=1.2em,align=left}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Initials
  \item Age
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Preliminary Condition
    \item Support
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Imaging
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I really like this approach in implicit methods. Can you compare your approach to Zarko's approach internally? - - I think the only difference is that your method is implicit, while Zarko's method is explicit making it more expansible to different cases, etc if you need the usual enumeration in the same document. - - However, I really like the simplicity and implicity of this proposal. I think the two lines are necessary and sufficient for the effect. I cannot think any simpler implicit method.

Comment: Is it possible to automate the vertical spacing so that it is the same between all items?

Comment: @HomerWhite: This depends on the class options. I'm loading `article` with the default size - `10pt`. As such, you can add `itemsep=4pt plus 2pt minus 1pt` to your options. Under `11pt` use `itemsep=4.5pt plus 2pt minus 1pt`; under `12pt` use `itemsep=5pt plus 2.5pt minus 1pt`.

Comment: @Masi: There is probably no difference between the two *except* that [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows you to change things locally as well. So, while you can set the options globally (or even create a new list if you wish), you can also use `\begin{enumerate}[<options>]` to locally change `<options>`. Doing this explicitly by setting the different lengths is also possible, but more cumbersome.